# Too many arguments for fmap

Tags: haskell, functor

The first argument, that `fmap` is expected is a function with one argument.

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Then I tried as follow in prelude:

```
Prelude> x = fmap (\x y -> x * y)
```

As you can see, the first argument to `fmap` is a function, that has two arguments. Why does the compiler let it pass?

The function that I pass to `fmap` above has two arguments not one!

Comment: Because, in Haskell, all functions are considered curried

Comment: This is abstraction over arity, which is possible with languages that support first class functions. Instead of having to pay attention to the arity of a multi-argument function, you have to keep an eye on the function sequence.

Comment: This is actually a very common thing to do in Haskell with applicatives. `f <$> x <*> y` means `fmap f x <*> y`. For example, `(*) <$> [2, 3] <*> [5, 7]` means `[(2 *), (3 *)] <*> [5, 7]`, which evaluates to `[2 * 5, 2 * 7, 3 * 5, 3 * 7]` or `[10, 14, 15, 21]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell does not actually have functions with more (or less) than one argument. A "two-argument function" is really just a function that takes one argument and produces another function that takes another argument. That is, `\x y -> x * y` is just a syntactic short cut for `\x -> \y -> x * y`. This concept is known as currying.

So this should explain what's happening in your example. Your `fmap` will simply turn an `f` of numbers into an `f` of functions. So, for example, `x [1,2,3]` would produce the list `[\y -> 1 * y, \y -> 2 * y, \y -> 3 * y]` (a.k.a. `[(1*), (2*), (3*)]`).

Answer (score 2):

You have **defined a function**. One of the fundamental aspects of functional programming that functions can be parameters, stored into variables, etc.

If we then query the **type** of `x`, we get:

```
Prelude> :t x
x :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f (a -> a)
```

So `x` is now a function that takes as input a *`Functor` with `a` applied on that function*, and returns the an element of a type with the same functor, but applied with `a -> a`.

So you can for instance *apply a list* on `x`, like:

```
Prelude> :t x [1,4,2,5]
x [1,4,2,5] :: Num a => [a -> a]
```

So now we have a *list of functions*, that is *equivalent* to:

```
[\x -> 1*x, \x -> 4*x, \x -> 2*x, \x -> 5*x]
```